TCA Composable Architecture- No such module 'Testing'
I'm trying to follow the composable architecture tutorial about testing https://pointfreeco.github.io/swift-composable-architecture/main/tutorials/composablearchitecture/01-03-testingyourfeature/
But i am stuck at the very beginning
I am trying to import the Testing module:
import ComposableArchitecture
import Testing

@testable import MyApp

But I have this error:

No such module 'Testing'

Did I miss something ?

Is your file put in test target?

Yes, it is in the test target

https://github.com/swiftlang/swift-testing

Because Swift Testing is ship with XCode 16 so try to update your XCode to lastest version: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/testing/
